# Loading image to canvas after retrieving from camera roll (cordova)

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm fetching a file from the iOS camera roll, which returns a uri in this form:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/90849385-6FC7-4C4E-8220-7585312C3DFB/tmp/filename.jpg
```

I receive this uri from this function:

```
function openFilePicker(selection) {

    var srcType = Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM;
    var options = setOptions(srcType);
    var func = createNewFileEntry;

    navigator.camera.getPicture(function cameraSuccess(imageUri) {

    loadToCanvas(imageUri);

    }, function cameraError(error) {
    console.debug("Unable to obtain picture: " + error, "app");

    }, options);
}
```

and pass it to this function:

```
function loadToCanvas(path) {
    console.log(path);

    var ctx = document.getElementById('image');
    ctx = ctx.getContext('2d');
    var hero = new Image();   

    hero.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(hero, 0, 0);
    }; 

    hero.src = path;
}
```

The image is not showing in the canvas but there are no errors in the evothings console. What am I missing? Surely if cordova has the means of returning this uri to me then I should have access to the file, yeah? Thanks!

Comment: Where is `img1` defined? `ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);`

Comment: Sorry - just a typo.